# iterating through radiobuttons

Tags: actionscript-3, radio-button

Is there a way to iterate through radiobuttons belonging to a certain group or movieclip?
Like this:

```
private var radioButtons:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("radioButtons");
for (var i:int = 0; i < radioButtons.numRadioButtons; i++ )
{
    trace(radioButtons);
// Here i want to do something like this: radioButtons[i].label = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
radioButtons.getRadioButtonAt( i )
```

[getRadioButtonAt documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html#getRadioButtonAt())

Comment: Thanks a bunch! No idea how i could've missed this :/